# How to use Database Transactions in Laravel 5 with Codeception?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, codeception

I am testing my Laravel5 API with Codeception and I have noticed the rollback functionality that comes with Codeception can get a little slow at times because of the huge SQL dump I have provided it with. One solution is to use SQLite to make it faster but I wish to stick with MySQL.

I think that the database transactions feature in Laravel 5 can help in speeding things up. But I am struggling to realize how to use it with codeception and can it be used in the first place too.

```
<?php 

$I = new ApiTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('create a new comment');
$I->haveHttpHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . file_get_contents('tests/api/token'));
$I->sendPost('comments', [
    "document_id" => "2",
    "comment_type_id" => "2",
    "user_id" => "2",
    "body" => "Testing"
]);
$I->seeResponseCodeIs(200);
$I->seeResponseIsJson();
$I->seeResponseContainsJson(['status' => 'success']);
$I->seeInDatabase('comment', [
    "document_id" => "2",
    "comment_type_id" => "2",
    "user_id" => "2",
    "body" => "Testing"
]);
```

This is a codeception test I have written. Now I tried to add:

```
\DB::beginTransaction(); // At the start
\DB::rollback(); // At the end
```

But it did not work.

I even tried to wrap up the whole test in this:

```
\DB::transaction(function () {
    // Whole Test here
});
```

But even this did not work out. I still see the new comments in the DB after running the test. So what am I doing wrong and how to go around it?

Comment: You could use `blackhole` engine for these tests, if you don't need any data persisted.

Answer (score 0):

What does your `tests/api.suite.yml` file look like?

It works for me, mine looks like this:

```
class_name: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - Helper\Api
        - Asserts
        - Laravel5:
            environment_file: .env
        - REST:
            depends: Laravel5
```

Adding this might help - but I didn't need to

```
- Laravel5:
    cleanup: true
```